# regex to validate strings with numbers and letters

Tags: regex

I need help to create a regex to validate one string, the string must be 12 characters, they can all be numbers or they can be 11 numbers and a letter, the letter can be anywhere between those numbers.

Some examples:

20710117540C

00A109822346

005109822346

K05109822346

// error cases

KY0510982234

KY05109822345

5505109822345

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex that will meet your requirements,

```
^(?:\d{12}|(?=\d*[a-zA-Z]\d*$)[\da-zA-Z]{12})$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of string
- `(?:` - Start of non-grouping pattern
- `\d{12}` - Matches exactly 12 digits
- `|` - alternation for another case where 11 characters can be any digits and one letter
- `(?=\d*[a-zA-Z]\d*$)` - Look ahead to ensure the the incoming data consists of some digits and exactly one occurrence of alphabet
- `[\da-zA-Z]{12}` - Consume 12 characters consisting of numbers and alphabet
- `)$` - End of non capturing group and end of input

**[Demo1](https://regex101.com/r/0KoGRT/1)**

Another simple regex you can use is this,

```
^(?=\d*[a-zA-Z]?\d*$)[\da-zA-Z]{12}$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of string
- `(?=\d*[a-zA-Z]?\d*$)` - Look ahead ensuring the input contains some digits and either one alphabet or no alphabets.
- `[\da-zA-Z]{12}` - Match and consume exactly 12 characters
- `$` - End of input.

**[Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/0KoGRT/2)**

Comment: Thank you very much!! it works perfectly.